# Does hdfs snapshot works on appending data?

Tags: hdfs, parquet, snapshot

I understood that hdfs snapshot keeps tracks of added or deleted files from a directory. How is the behaviour when i have files (PARQUET) that are appended continuously?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a snapshot of a directory/file, they are added in the subdirectory */.snapshot* , so they are ordered by date ascending whatever the file format is! There's no a maximum number of snapshots.

> hdfs snapshot keeps tracks of added or deleted files from a directory

Correct me if I'm wrong, but a snapshot keeps track of every single change (even in the file) and not just of the added and deleted files from a directory.

I hope this helps you to understand their behaviour!

[HDFS snapshots documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsSnapshots.html)